# Jquery 1.9 preg replace text in url

Tags: jquery, text, replace, preg-replace

Below is my **local url**

**Example :**   `http://localhost/project/admin/resources/view_category/199`

I need delete all text after resources and replace it with jquery

**Example :** `http://localhost/project/admin/resources/please_help`).

Syntax of preg_math functions i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.split()`

```
var str = "http://localhost/project/admin/resources/view_category/199"
    str = str.split("resources")[0] + "resources/please_help"
    console.log(str); //"http://localhost/project/admin/resources/please_help"
```